# Alternative to ST_ClosestPoint, one which returns a vertex of the geometry

Tags: postgis, point, vertices

ST_ClosestPoint returns the closest point on a geometry, as in the example at

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html

What I need is to get the closest point which is *already* a part of the geometry.

Example:

```
geometry = [1,2,3,4]
Point = any position
```

`ST_ClosestPoint(geometry,point)` returns something like `[2.5]` which is *between* existing vertexes.

How can I get a result without interpolation (so it should be 1,2,3 or 4 and nothing else possible)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You probably need a combination of [`ST_Dump()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) and [`ST_Distance()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) (with ORDER BY and LIMIT) in the solution.

I think we really could benefit from a ST_ClosestVertex() and maybe a ST_SnapToVertex() function added to PostGIS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. You're right, I was really confused that I could not find such a function in the postgis-catalogue.But this example in combination with `order-by MIN(st_distance(**))` ([http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html)) should be an solid solution to find the position of the closest poin of the existing geometry.

Comment: (FYI, I believe your answer counts more as a comment to my answer.)